# Objective-C ARC Error: -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having a problem trying to migrate my iPhone app to the new ARC technology. When I try to convert the code, the following error shows up 29 times:

```
 Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 Error
 -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi
```

What does this mean? And more importantly, how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a few code examples for some of these errors?

Comment: The errors are not related to a specific part of the code. When I click on them, nothing happens.

Comment: I just found out what a fragile abi is. It is a specific compiler mode. But how can I turn of fragile abi compiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Apple's developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/111890)

> This is an unfortunate bug in Seed 3, where the migrator and simulator
>   aren't working well together.  To address this, just switch to a
>   device target, then do migration.

Comment: What do I do if I get this error in the 32-Bit version of a Mac OS X app, but not the 64-Bit version? Is it correct that ARC is not supported in 32-Bit Mac apps under Lion? The transitioning guide seems to indicate this (search for "64"): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Comment: Answer: 32-Bit + ARC is a no-go, at least under Lion. I tested it by creating a new Mac app and change the allowed architecture to include 32-Bit.

Comment: 4.2? It was a pre-release version.

Answer (score 2):

change compiler.

Set the project compiler to "LLVM GCC 4.2", instead of "Apple LLVM 3.0"; ARC is only supported when you use Apple LLVM. To set the project compiler, in your Project, under "Build Settings", and then under "Build Options", there is a settings for "Compiler for Objective-C". Change that value to "LLVM GCC 4.2