# ARC error : -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C ARC Error: -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965990/objective-c-arc-error-fobjc-arc-is-not-supported-with-fragile-abi)

Clang LLVM 1.0 Error
error: -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi

I'm buildin an OSX app and I get the same error when I compile it with "Profile", to work with Instruments. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the "possible duplicate" question. That one refers to iOS; this one refers to Mac OS X, and the solution is different in each case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ARC is only available to 64-bit applications in OS X.  Therefore, you must set your application's architecture to "64-bit Intel" in the build settings.  If you want to support 32-bit OS X systems then you cannot use ARC.

"Fragile ABI" refers to the old "Legacy" Objective-C runtime, which is what 32-bit OS X applications use.  iOS and 64-bit OS X apps use the "Modern" Objective-C runtime.